# ios - new project gives error on push notifications that they can only be managed by UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

This is the second project I am doing with ios and I do not recall having this error the first time. I am wondering if I did't set some setting right.

On push notifications, I get this crash:

```
Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.
```

Any idea how to fix it? Is there some setting that needs to be on?

Thanks!

Comment: The controller you're pushing from has to be embedded in a navigation controller. Is it?

Comment: @rdelmar I am not sure how to make it embedded in the navigation controller. I have not explicitly made a navigation controller. Is that something I have to do?

Comment: Yes you do. How did you start your project -- from what template? Are you using storyboards?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes I am using storyboards. The way I started it was in x-code I just did file->new project and went through the basic steps.

Comment: The basic steps include selecting a type of application (i.e. template) like Utility or Single View or....  Which was this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming you started with a single view project, just select that view controller, go to the Editor menu, and choose "Embed in", then choose Navigation Controller.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed :) I forgot I had to do this.

Comment: by the way, for my original app, Apple required some sort of a tab bar navigation. Is that something I should also embed my application in?

Comment: Only if you want one. I don't know what you mean by "Apple required" a tab bar navigation -- it's only required if you want to have a tab bar controller in your project.

Comment: hmmm yeah I think I will need some sort of a navigation bar so people can jump around the app.  What is the way to do that? I mean, what should I embed in the navigation controller?

Comment: If you want to "jump around" then you probably do want a tab bar based application. You should just start from the Tabbed Application template if you want to do that. I would also strongly recommend that you read (and study) the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" in the apple docs.